# Importing Excel into a Datagrid

Tags: c#, excel, datagrid, oledb, oledbdataadapter

I am attempting to bring an excel file into my program so that I may work with the data and export it. I am using the OleDB to access the access file and am attempting to pass it to a datatable so that I can view it and work with it in a winform. Here is the code I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using System.Threading;

namespace DataImportServices
{
    public class ExcelImport : IDataImport
    {
        public DataTable ImportData(OpenFileDialog openFile)
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();

            string query;
            var hasHeaders = false;
            var HDR = hasHeaders ? "Yes" : "No";
            string connectionString;

            if (openFile.FileName.Substring(openFile.FileName.LastIndexOf(".")).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
            {
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + openFile.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
            }
            else
            {
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + openFile.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
            }

            using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                cn.Open();
                DataTable schemaTable = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
                DataRow schemaRow = schemaTable.Rows[0];
                string sheet = schemaRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                if (!sheet.EndsWith("_"))
                {
                    query = "SELECT * FROM [" + openFile.FileName + "]";
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn))
                    {
                         dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                         dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable); //The error occurs here with a "" is not an acceptable. If I put a name ie "Data" it says its not an adorecord.
                    }
                }                
            }
            return (dataTable);
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I am incurring is when I am trying to fill the dataTable with the OleDBAdapter(dataAdapter). It throws an exception asking for an ADODBrecordset despite having an override for just the DataTable. How can I work around this? Or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like EpPlus. This support excel native without the use of ole or excel.

You can load your data as an array and access it directly.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LinqExample

Answer (score 0):

You could try reading excel content with Exportable. Is a tiny library that I developed time ago and now is distributed on Nuget as OpenSource.

Basically, you can read an Excel file like this:

```
IImportEngine engine = new ExcelImportEngine();
var key = engine.AddContainer<DummyPersonWithAttributes>();
engine.SetDocument(pathToFile); //or MemoryStream instance
var data = engine.GetList<DummyPersonWithAttributes>(key);
```

You could get more info on [here](https://github.com/vvenegasv/exportable)